# Can any domain in the Riemann sphere be approximated by finitely connected Jordan domains?

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, connectedness

Is it true that for any domain $\Omega \subset \bar{\mathbb{C}}$ we can find finitely connected Jordan domains $\Omega_n$ such that
$$
\Omega_n \subset \bar{\Omega}_n \subset \Omega_{n+1} \subset \Omega
$$
and
$$
\Omega = \bigcup \Omega_n.
$$
I'm reading a book that kind of implicitly uses this, so I assume this must be an easy/standard argument?